# RxJs: subscription performed twice

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I've created this subscription:

```
this.store$.combineLatest(
      this.store$.select(fromRoot.getUserEntity),
      this.store$.select(fromRoot.getSelectedSourceIds),
      (store, user, selectedSourceIds) => ({user: user, selectedSourceIds: selectedSourceIds}) 
    )
    .filter((proj) => proj.user.id != null && proj.user.logged)
    .do((proj) => this.store$.dispatch({type: 'DELETE_CARDS', payload: {username: proj.user.username, tokens: proj.selectedSourceIds}}))
    .take(1)
    .subscribe();
```

It's performed (`do` code) twice.

Could somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting some undefined values the first time. Try using `zip` instead of `combineLatest`.